# Some Windows services not visible remotely

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-service

I'm struggling to figure out what is going on, but it has a pretty widespread effect on a system I'm working with. I originally asked this on stack overflow and It was recommended I check here. [OP StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846286/windows-services-not-visible-remotely/51846620?noredirect=1#comment90688789_51846620)

I have several machines running a service, but when I try to query the service (both in .net and in powershell) the service is not found. When I connect to the machine via RDP, the service shows up. I've already confirmed that I had permissions on the service, including granting explicit permissions to the service for my user using subinacl. All the servers are running Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter including the domain controller where all the machines are connected to.

I do get a result back from get-service -computername $server but it doesn't list the service I'm looking for. Is there a group policy or windows configuration that I'm missing here? Why would some services show up remotely but not all of them? I think this may have something to do with 32 bit vs 64 bit applications. The previous version of the service I was dealing with was 32 bit but now it is 64 and the problem is showing up. That would also explain why some but not all of the services show up.

Any tips/advice on what to look for would be greatly appreciated. Using Domain admin does resolve the issue, but for obvious reasons, I can't be granting everyone domain admin access.

**EXAMPLE1**

Command:

```
Get-Service -Computername $servername -Name 'AdobeARMservice'
```

Running Remotely Result:

```
Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name
 'AdobeARMservice'. At line:1 char:1
 + Get-Service -Computername $servername -Name 'AdobeARMservice'
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (AdobeARMservice:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandExcep
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

Running Locally Result:

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  AdobeARMservice    Adobe Acrobat Update Service
```

**EXAMPLE2**

This issue can also be seen in the microsoft service list.

While locally on the machine:[image: LocalServiceImage]

While remote: [image: RemoteServiceImage]

Comment: The first thing to double-check is that you're successfully querying the remote machine rather than the local machine: try it on a service that is installed on the local machine but not the remote one.  Otherwise, uh ... it could be something weird about the service permissions, you can check these with `sc sdshow` at the command line - if the services that work have different permissions to the ones that don't, copy and paste both outputs into your post.  Finally, have you checked that you're running the 64-bit version of Powershell?  Conversely, what does 32-bit Powershell run locally show?